# Sum multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a table like this:

```
id    mod    n1    n2    n3
1     1      1     1
1     2            2
1     3                  3
2     1      1
2     2            2
3     1      1
```

And I want to sum up each value for all the rows for a specific id into a column call total, but I don't want to group the id together because they have different mod number. I want a result like this:

```
id    mod   total
1     1     7
1     2     7
1     3     7
2     1     3
2     2     3
3     1     1
```

I can't use group by because it will give me the total for just each individual rows. How do I achieve the result that I want?

Comment: I don't understand the calcul behind the total column ?

Comment: With Windows Functions you could get a single line query to return the resultset you need. Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't support them.

Comment: @njzk2: If you look at the first table, you'll see that total matches with the totals for all items against `id`. The mod does not seem to have any real impact so `total` appears to be a redundant column for each record in the second table.

Comment: @njzk2 CHECK ALL VALUES FOR 1 ID YOU GET THE IDEA HOW 7 COME .. FIRST THREE ROW .

Comment: Why would you want to keep the `mod` column in the resultset when it conveys no information?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT `table`.`id`, `mod`, mySum
FROM `table` 
JOIN (SELECT `id`, SUM(n1) + SUM(n2) + SUM(n3) AS mySum
        FROM `table` GROUP BY `id`) as grpTable
ON `table`.`id` = `grpTable`.`id`
```

Not sure about the performance of this though...

Comment: I think it would require __`table`.__ prefix before `id` in the select clause

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
select t.id, t1.mod, t.total
from tab t1
join (select id, sum( IFNULL(n1,0)+ IFNULL(n2,0)+ IFNULL(n3,0)) as total
      from tab 
      group by id) t on t.id=t1.id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT `id`, `mod`, (SUM(n1) + SUM(n2) + SUM(n3)) AS total
FROM `table` 
 GROUP BY `id`,`mod`
```

Answer (score 1):

The second answer was correct, all it needed was correct calls to `ifnull`

```
select t.id, t1.mod, t.total
from test.source t1
join (select id, sum( IFNULL(n1,0)+ IFNULL(n2,0)+ IFNULL(n3,0)) as total
      from test.source 
      group by id) t on t.id=t1.id
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. Worked in Oracle. Check if keywords need to be changed in mysql.

```
SELECT x.id, x.mod, y.sum
  FROM table x,
       (SELECT id, sum(nvl(n1, 0) + nvl(n2, 0) + nvl(n3, 0)) sum
          FROM table
         GROUP BY id) y
 WHERE x.id = y.id;
```